# Let $g = x^3 + 1$ and $f = x^2 + 1$ How to show that there doesn't exist function $k$, such that $g = k \circ f$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The task is

> Let $\mathcal F = \{f \mid f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$ and
>   define relationship $R$ on $\mathcal F$ as follows:
>
> $$R = \{(f,g) \in \mathcal F \times \mathcal F \mid \exists h \in
>  \mathcal F (f = h \circ g)\}$$
>
> Let functions $f,g,h$ be the functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$
>   defined by the formulas $f(x) = x^2 + 1$,$g(x) = x^3 + 1$,$h(x) = x^4
>  + 1$. Prove that $hRf$, but it is not the case that $gRf$.

I was able to show that $hRf$. Let $k \in \mathcal F$ such that

$$k(x) = x^2 - 2x + 2$$

Then $f(x) = k(g(x)) = (k \circ g)(x)$ for all $x$.

Now my question is, how to show that $(g,f)$ is not in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x^{3}+1=k(x^{2}+1)$ then $x=1$ gives $2= k(2)$ and $x=-1$ gives $0=k(2)$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @Nelver Yes, sorry for the mistake.